# How do I ensure that the cell is not being filled up?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having an issue where the cell is being filled up. I would want it to be empty and only filled up if the payment date is being inputted. I'm rather new and would need your kind help.

[image]

```
function dateplay() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const data=sh.getRange(2,10,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  const output=sh.getRange(2,11,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  output.forEach(function(e,i){
    let dt=new Date(data[i][0]);    
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+daysInNextMonth(dt.getMonth()+1));
    e[0]=dt;
  });
  sh.getRange(2,11,sh.getLastRow(),1).setValues(output);
}
function daysInNextMonth(m=0) {
  return new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),m+1,0).getDate();
}
```

Ensure that column K is not being filled up entirely.

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. Your question may be closed, if it isn't self contained. Your table should be a minimal example.[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.prototype.toString.call()` to detect blanks and other values that are not dates, like this:

```
function setDueDates() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const paymentDates = sheet.getRange('J2:J').getValues().flat();
  const dueDatesRange = sheet.getRange('K2:K');
  const dueDates = paymentDates.map(date => {
    if (!date || (Object.prototype.toString.call(date) !== '[object Date]')) {
      return [null];
    }
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
    return [date];
  });
  dueDatesRange.setValues(dueDates);
}
```